# Узнать количество страниц А4 в поле BLOB MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

В поле `VARBINARY(MAX)` хранится файл. Я знаю, что за формат у этого файла. **Возможно ли как то узнать средствами `MS SQL`** **количество страниц файла**, если это `PDF`, `RTF`, `DOC`, `DOCX` или прочий "многостраничный" файл?